# ros arduino bridge

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i want to install ros arduino bridge but i don't know which command.
i try `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-arduino-bridge` but it don't work.
could you give me the correct command to intall arduino bridge please?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234853/ros-arduino-bridge/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, did you try this? here you can find the installation steps of the ros_arduino_bridge Stack https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge/blob/master/README.md#installation-of-the-ros_arduino_bridge-stack

---

Originally posted by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) with karma: 123 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0